# Pesquisa no FullCalendar.js

Tags: fullcalendar

Como fazer que ao digitar um texto no input o FullCalendar.js ele filtra o conteudo. Já tentei o eventRender mais não tive sucesso.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
  let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    locale: "pt-br",
    plugins: ["interaction", "dayGrid", "timeGrid", "list"],
    header: {
      left: "prev,next",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay"
    },
    customRender: true,
    editable: false,
    navLinks: true, 
    eventLimit: true,
    timeZone: "UTC",
    events: {
      url: "json/events.json",
      failure: function() {
      }
    },
    eventDataTransform: function(eventData) {
      return {
        title: eventData.diaSemana,
        start: eventData.dataAssembleia
      };
    },
    eventClick: function(eventData) {
      eventData.el.style.borderColor = "red";
      alert("O Evento é: " + eventData.event.title);
    }
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="numero" placeholder="Nome do Evento" />
    <div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Nesse seu filtro você vai recarregar os dados do servidor ? ou quer filtrar os eventos que já estão setados no callendar ?

Comment: Tipo quando a pessoa digitar diaSemana só aparecer no calendario o que ela deseja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função para pegar os eventos do `FullCalendar` e adicionar uma `class` nos itens que deseja ocultar de acordo com o filtro, e chamar ela toda vez que o seu input de filtro for alterado.

Exemplo da `function`:

```
function filterCalendar() {
    var events = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('clientEvents');

    events.map(function (event) {
        console.log(event);

        // o objeto event possui todas as propriedades que voce difiniu nele.
        // Voce consegue fazer o seu filtro por qualquer uma delas, por exemplo o titulo.
        if (evento.title.indexOf($('#inputFilter').val())) {
            event.className[0] = 'filter-hidden';        
        } else {
            event.className[0] = '';        
        }

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);        
    });
}
```

E no seu `css`você define para esta classe esconder os objetos, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
.filter-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Links Uteis da Doc do FullCalendar:

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/clientEvents

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/updateEvent

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/removeEvents

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object